# Does "pants" more commonly mean "trousers" or "underpants"?

Tags: meaning, british-english, subcontinental-english, transatlantic-differences, world-english

In the UK, I've heard pants being used as slang for underpants (or was it in *Bridget Jones' Diary*?), whereas in India it almost exclusively means "trousers".

Describing the meaning of "put your pants on one leg at a time", [this link](http://www.learn-english-today.com/idioms/idiom-categories/clothes-idioms.htm) says:

> To say that someone *puts their pants
>    on one leg at a time* means that the
>    person is a human being no different
>    from anyone else.

The idiom's origin [seems to refer to trousers](http://benmuse.typepad.com/ben_muse/2005/05/they_put_their_.html)
but I'm wondering whether someone reading this might think "underpants" rather than trousers?

Comment: Another interesting question is why "pants" has always meant "trousers" in India, given that Indian usage typically follows/followed British English… has there been a change in British English?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR : exactly - which i why i mentioned India - we usually speak/follow UK and not US English

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the UK "Pants" typically refers to underwear.
(Where it is also a slang term for "bad". As in "That's pants".)

In other parts of the world, notably the USA, "pants" refers to trousers.

Comment: Ok, so any Brit would think "underpants" even for the phrase?

Comment: No, any Brit would think trousers. Generally underpants don't have legs.

Comment: @josek with regards the phrase, it doesn't matter which meaning of "pants" is used, the implication is that the person has 2 legs and that they put one of their legs in to the article of clothing at a time. (Variations in ways of getting dressed notwithstanding.)

Comment: Ha, that's weird. I've never thought of it as referring to the _person's_ legs, only trouser legs. I wonder, would you say 'He puts his jacket on one arm at a time' or 'one sleeve at a time'...?

Comment: @ElendilTheTall  I put the jacket ON one of my arms at a time. Or I put my arms IN one of the sleeves at a time.

Comment: Accepting yours for the added `That's pants` explanation.

Comment: @Matt Lacey: That's valid but different. To put it another way, would you say: 'He dons his jacket one arm at a time.' or 'one sleeve at a time.' By the way, this is all hypothetical, I know what you would say. :)

Comment: @ElendilTheTall  Ah, You guessed tthat I'd just say "he put his jacket on"! ;)

Comment: Not quite. I meant, what would the above idiom read like if it referred to a jacket not pants/trousers, i.e., if you remove the possibility of confusion between trouser legs and human legs.

Comment: @ElendilTheTall I think either is valid as there isn't the opportunity for the same confusion as with legs.

Comment: FWIW: This use of "pants" (as slang for "bad") by UKers is one of the more befuddling Britishisims we USAsians are regularly confronted with.

Answer (score 13):

In US usage pants means trousers.
In UK usage pants means underpants.

The popularity of US films and TV programmes means that most English speakers are likely to have some awareness of the US usage and will correctly understand phrases that use pants to mean trousers.

Comment: Yes, most people will understand the US usage in context but it can cause hilarity - such as when an American girl tells a Scottish guy he has nice pants.

Comment: And a disaster when an Am. guy tells a Scott. girl.

Comment: @neil Especially if he's wearing a kilt!

Comment: Once when I had green paint on the arse of my trousers, an American exclaimed 'you've got green paint on your fanny! I looked down, suddenly, horrified...

Answer (score 4):

In British English, *pants* means *underpants* or, informally, *nonsense*.
In American English, *pants* means *trousers*; the singular form is used as adjective.

> [BrEn] He thought we were going to be absolute pants.
>   [AmEn] His pant leg was broken.

Comment: Not so much "nonsense" as "dreadful". I remember very clearly the first time I heard this piece of slang (around 1996), and while in context I understood what was meant, I found it very strange.

Answer (score 4):

I'm English and I've  never called underpants "pants" this is a relatively recent use of the word from about the early Nineties. I went to 8 different schools around England, north and south, in the Seventies (don't ask) no one ever called underpants  "pants".

Comment: Certainly growing up in the eighties, I never heard "underpants" used in ordinary speech.  When I did come across it it seemed pretentious - why would you call them as "_under_pants" when there is no other sort of pants (in BrE).

Comment: I went to fewer schools in the Seventies although we did move around the country, but "underpants" was hardly ever used. The early-Nineties phenomenon is the pejorative use of "pants" as "dreadful" (which does mean that the word itself is more common since then).

Comment: Very odd. I went to fewer schools but had relatives all over and all the children I knew (born in late 60's) used "pants" for underpants almost universally. What else would you call them?

Comment: I went to school from the late 1940s and I have never described my lower underwear as anything other than 'pants'. Nor did anyone at school with me refer to their 'underpants'. I did know one person at school who used to refer to his 'underpants', and others used to look at him a bit strangely when he did so. I have never heard 'pants' used to mean 'dreadful'. Perhaps I am too old. By the 1990s I was a highly stressed manager working about 12 hours a day. I lost that decade completely so far as popular culture went.

Comment: I went to school in the 80/90s in northern England and the word pants meant trousers, get your pants on and get to school.  Over the last 10 years, people saying things are pants and implying they are bad has never made sense to me

Answer (score 3):

In Australian usage, 'pants' usually (but not always) refers to 'trousers'. From the [Macquarie Dictionary](http://www.macquariedictionary.com.au):

1. trousers.
2. underpants, especially women's.
3. (phrase) be caught with one's pants down, Colloquial to be caught unexpectedly and ill-prepared.
4. by the seat of one's pants, Colloquial
   a. without the benefit of prior instruction.
   b. deprived of the technical aids usually available, as in the case of an aircraft pilot with faulty instruments.
5. get into someone's pants, Colloquial to have sexual intercourse with someone.
6. ... the pants off someone, Colloquial (humorous) used after a verb, as an intensifier: that lecturer bores the pants off me; this'll scare the pants off her; I'll sue the pants off him!
7. wear the pants, to be the dominant partner in a relationship. [abbreviation of pantaloons]

Interestingly, the loan-word 'pantsu' (パンツ) in Japanese suffers from the same conflicted identity - it can mean either underpants or trousers (though perhaps the former is more common).

Comment: '... it can mean either...' That would be even worse, actually.

Answer (score 2):

In Britain, pants almost always refers to underpants (and more specifically men's underpants). 'Trousers' is used everywhere 'pants' is in US English, including the idiom you refer to.

Answer (score 2):

Nonsense!
"Pants" are definitely not underwear exclusively in the UK.
Maybe it's a regional thing. Where I live in North West England, pants is a general name for all types of lower outer two legged garments and has been since I grew up in the early seventies! Trousers are just a formal pair of pants.
Boys wear underpants and girls wear knickers.
I found out recently that a large proportion of the country call their underwear "pants" and it makes me wonder how over the years we have all been misunderstanding each other. 
Interesting how Australia/India use nearly always follow the UK rather that USA but still use the same dialect as my own region in the UK. 
I wonder how long the word "pants" to mean underwear has been around in the UK and which came first. And how we all got so muddled!

Answer (score 1):

> In the UK, I've heard pants being used as slang for underpants (or was
>   it in Bridget Jones' Diary?), whereas in India it almost exclusively
>   means "trousers".

First of all, that is not slang. Pants is the normal word in the UK. There is a difference in use of the word in different forms of English. In American English, it means what is known as trousers in the UK. If pants is used in India with the American definition, that suggests an American influence on the English learnt there.

This page explains it: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/pants_1?q=pants