# Difference between "slacks", "pants", and "trousers"?

Tags: differences, american-english

I wonder what differences are between usage of *slacks*, *pants*, and *trousers*? Their meanings seem the same by looking up *Google*’s Internet dictionary and *Wikipedia*.

Comment: Related: [Does “pants” more commonly mean “trousers” or “underpants”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10246/does-pants-more-commonly-mean-trousers-or-underpants)

Comment: Added AmE tag because to me "pants" definitely does not mean the same as "trousers"!

Comment: @AndrewLeach: What do pants mean to you?

Comment: More important (to me) than the reference of each of these word is the users.  "Slacks" and (to a slightly lesser extent) "trousers" are words used by older people, women, and people in the clothing industry.  In decades of life as a native English speaker, living in multiple countries that speak English, I don't think I've ever heard anyone outside of those three categories use those two words.  My mom talks about "slacks" and "trousers".  I just call everything "pants" and I'm done with it.

Comment: @Brandon: that's exactly my view of things (in AmE). It's all pants all the way.

Comment: @Mitch: yes you're right about American English.  Although England is not one of the countries in which I lived, I can 'hear' people from England using the word "trousers", so I suppose that's a partial amendment to what I wrote earlier.

Comment: In my experience in American English, "trousers" is seldom used unless it is an affectation of some kind. "Slacks" generally means something slightly more formal than denim and "Pants" usually means something like denim jeans but can also be used as a synonym for both "Slacks" and "Trousers". "Dress Pants" or "Suit Pants" might be used for men's or women's business bifurcated garments.

Comment: @ΜετάEd Is there a meta question explaining why a question that had a research attempt is still general reference?

Comment: Dunno. If it's not obvious feel free to post one.

Comment: @Tim In British English, "pants" is short for "underpants."  It is a source of much mirth.

Comment: Don't forget "strides".

Answer (score 17):

An excert from [here](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1284747):

> Slacks implies pants of certain materials which are not part of a suit
>   (jeans are not slacks, and you would not refer to the pair of trousers
>   that came with a suit as "slacks".) It is also more common to use
>   "slacks" to refer to pants worn by women, while men would wear
>   "trousers". Meanwhile, "pants" could refer to slacks, or trousers, or
>   jeans, or just about any form of two-legged outer garment for the
>   lower body.
>
> Note that in AE, "pants" by itself is never understood to mean
>   underwear of any kind, and must be altered in some form (either as
>   "underpants" or as "panties") to have that meaning.
>
> Bill: What's this I hear that the boss walked into your office while
>   you were changing your clothes and caught you in your underwear? Tom:
>   No, but she nearly caught me in my underwear; luckily, I had just put
>   my pants on.

This is an AE perspective but, I would say that trousers and pants are synonyms. With both being any outer garment that covers both legs separately and goes from waist to ankles.
Technically slacks is also a synonym, but the informal definition I most frequently hear is that slacks = dress pants. I.E. Pants that you might wear if you were trying to look nice.

Comment: The excerpt you quote contradicts your definition of "slacks = dress pants", in the sense that a suit is about as dressy as anybody gets nowadays, yet nobody would call the leg coverings that came with said suit "slacks".

Comment: Isn't it neat how usage varies? Personally, I would call suit pants slacks if worn without the jacket... but I didn't want to modify the quote.

Comment: I've never heard suit pants called *slacks*.  What part of the US do you live in?

Comment: @Brandon I generally wouldn't say slacks as the term is more of an occasional term used by my elders... But if I did I would only mean suit pants in the sense of the kind of pants that may be paired with a suit jacket. For your information, I was raised in a suburb of Chicago.

Comment: As I understand "suit", the jacket and pants always come together.  If you pair the jacket with pants of a non-identical material, then it's not a suit (again, as I've always heard the term used, and had it explained to me when I've asked for fashion advice).

Comment: @iconoclast In my experience, it used to be common that when one bought a suit, one got two pair of slacks with it as they wore faster than the jacket. Yes, all identical material in keeping with the notion of a suit, but marketed as an extra pair of slacks. Currently Men's Wearhouse, a popular discount men's wear store, offer "suit separates" which include suit pants marketed as slacks.

Comment: I've pretty much only heard "slacks" in reference to khaki pants (or trousers, if you prefer.) I've never heard any other garment refered to as such. This has been my experience in both the Mid-Atlantic and (to a much lesser extent) in the Rocky Mountains, where we pretty much just wear jeans all the time anyway.

Comment: In 2018, no one under the age of 60 ever says "trousers" in the US. They're slacks.

Answer (score 14):

I know the question is tagged AmE - but that wasn't in the original, and hasn't (yet) been confirmed by OP, so I don't see anything wrong with answering from a BrE perspective.

In the UK, *pants* almost always means *underpants*. And as OED says, *slacks* are *loosely-cut trousers for informal wear, esp. those worn by women.*

I think for many Americans, *pants* and *trousers* are effectively synonyms. But so far as I'm aware, *"esp. those worn by women"* tends to apply to slacks on both sides of the Atlantic.

Comment: Google does something curious if you search for "men's slacks".  Check it out.

Comment: In the UK, pants just means what Americans call underpants. I'm surprised by your mention of "slacks". I haven't heard that word used in the UK, at all. It seems to be an American English word.

Comment: @tchrist: what curious thing did you see? link to yours? I saw [two peaks in AmE](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=men%27s+slacks&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3) and [no hits at all in BrE](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=men%27s+slacks&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3).

Comment: @Mitch It counts *pants* as hits for *slacks*. I found that curious.

Comment: @tchrist: oh... _that_ is interesting.

Comment: @Tristan: [This NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wearing+slacks%2Cwearing+trousers&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3) shows that since the war, *wearing slacks/wearing trousers* occur about equally often in the US corpus. *Trousers* are 2-3 times more common in the UK corpus, but that hardly means *slacks* is "US-only" terminology. For example, OED specifically says *trunk=car luggage compartment*, or *faggot=homosexual*, for example, are [primarily] American. It doesn't say that about *slacks*, which is fine by me.

Comment: @tchrist I was expecting an easter egg.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Sorry, now you make me feel bad for letting you down.  I presume you know about [these](http://devstand.com/fun/google-easter-eggs/)?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: try an [alternative nGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=his+slacks%2Chis+trousers%2Chis+pants%2Cher+slacks%2Cher+trousers%2Cher+pants&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3) making trousers far more common than slacks in UK books

Comment: FumbleFingers: I didn't intend to give the impression that "slacks" is "US-only" terminology. I meant that it seems to be an American English word, at least in origin and most of its use. That's because, in all my decades, I can't think of even one example of hearing "slacks" used in the UK.

Comment: Instances of *slacks* in your NGram are swamped by the fact that you've included *his* as well as *her*. With just [her xxxs](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=her+pants%2Cher+slacks%2Cher+trousers&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) you get a truer picture - *slacks:38K, trousers:45K,* and (perhaps a bit sexist! :), *pants:213K*.

Answer (score 3):

An AE perspective:

> **pants** - The broadest term used for any full length two legged covering, male or female; covers both hard work clothes (jeans), casual (chinos, ducks, khakis, etc.) and dress outfits (suits, office wear, evening wear, even tuxedos). This is probably the most common term in general use. (See [ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pants,slacks,trousers&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3) below which is probably book references only)
>
> **slacks** - The next fairly broad term, covering all but work clothes or jeans. Women's dressier pants are often called slacks. Probably least used overall and more for women's clothing.
>
> **trousers** - Usually only used for dressier clothes, such as suit pants or finer pants often worn with a sports jacket, blazer or a dressier shirt. Usually reserved for men's clothing, with the possible exception of women's pants suits.

[image: ngram pants]

Comment: *Men's slacks* are where you find men's dress pants in a department store.

Comment: Men's Furnishings is where you find "pants" in Nordstrom, a popular American department store.  In Men's Clothing, one finds "dress trousers".  So not all stores are the same.

Comment: In Macy's, one of the largest department stores in the US, one subcategory in *Men's* is *pants*. There is also a *Suit Separates* subcategory where, a quick review, finds the bottoms referred to as *pants* across several brands. Brooks Brothers, a more classic men's store, lists *casual pants* and *dress trousers* as categories.

Answer (score 2):

A good dictionary is more useful for comparing regional usage and subtleties of difference than *Google* or *Wikipedia*. From *Macmillan Dictionary*:[¹](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/)

**trousers**

> a piece of clothing covering the body from the waist to the feet, divided into separate parts for each leg and worn by both men and women

**pants**

> (American edition) a piece of clothing that covers your body from your waist to your ankles and has a separate part for each leg
>   (British edition) a piece of underwear that covers the part of the body from the waist to the top of the legs

**slacks**

> (British edition). *trousers*, especially ones that are worn for informal occasions
>   (American edition) *pants*, especially ones that are worn for informal occasions

Comment: That AE definition for slacks is outrageous. Do a google image search for slacks. Do those look informal?

Comment: @DanielCook: Formality is relative. You might wear jeans to work, in which case those images would look formal. But in a suit-and-tie office, slacks would be decidedly informal.

Comment: @Robusto Indeed, I overreacted. Informal does not equal casual.

Comment: Slacks are more "dressy" than jeans, and often worn as day-to-day workplace attire, but are not part of a suit and also never worn when the occasion calls for formal dress.

Comment: ΜετάEd: How are AmE 'slacks' not what you call the bottom part of a suit? (I don't know...in that context, all three work for me, but I don't wear suits that often, nor am I a men's clothing specialist)

Comment: I think that categorising slacks as informal dates to an earlier time when people wore suits a lot more frequently, and slacks were, relatively speaking, more informal. Obviously, the arrival of jeans has pushed slacks back into the middle of the 'formality spectrum'.

Comment: Nobody in my circle, and as far as I can tell nobody in apparel profession, refers to the bottom of a suit as "slacks". The term is "trousers" or, informally, "pants". "Slacks" are loose, comfortable separates, casual but more dressy than jeans.

Comment: I think even the idea that a suit is formal is a recent notion.  AFAIK "formal wear" once meant a tuxedo.  If you look at depression-era pictures you can often find impoverished men in a three-piece suit, dingy and worn out though it may be.

Comment: @ΜετάEd Since when does the general public care what professionals think? If I need an extra pair of pants for my suit jacket, I'm not going to buy a new suit. I'll get myself some matching slacks. ;-)

Comment: @DanielCook Wear what you like. Technically you are not wearing a suit when you do that, though, as a suit is a jacket and trousers cut from the same cloth. When your jacket and slacks don't match, they may be stylish, but you're not wearing a suit.

Comment: This isn't a matter of professional lingo, either. I am simply saying that this is how I and people I know use the words, and we seem to use them the same way that the people in the apparel industry use them also. So I mean the reference to the apparel industry to add weight to my experience, not to substitute a technical term for a general term.

Comment: @ΜετάEd - As I noted above, gettting a second set of matching "slacks" (what we called them) when one bought a suit (1 jacket, two pair of trousers/pant/slacks to be used interchangably to reduce wear, all of the same cloth) used to be common.

Comment: I still think of slacks as dress pants.

Comment: @iconoclast when first introduced, even the tuxedo was considered informal, as evening clothing that gentlemen would wear only in the company of other gentlemen. If ladies were present, only a full dress suit ("white tie") would be formal enough. Nowadays white tie is a rarity even among the ruling classes, and black tie (a tuxedo) is as formal as you're likely to see.

Comment: @iconclast If you really want to get technical, the tuxedo is actually [semi-formal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-formal). It being more comfortable than a coat with tails.

Answer (score 2):

Well in Britain,

1) Slacks - (Clothing & Fashion) informal trousers worn by both sexes ([The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/slacks))

2) Pants - inadequate, displeasing, or of poor quality. Possible origin: underwear, called "pants" in Britain. ([Online Slang Dictionary](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/pants))

3) Trousers - (Clothing & Fashion) a garment shaped to cover the body from the waist to the ankles or knees with separate tube-shaped sections for both legs. ([The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/trousers))

I understand you want to know what the differences are in US-English, but that is the definition in UK-English.

---

In South Africa, it is the same as USA - English. Where we would call trousers as formal long pants. i.e.

Pants = shorts / baggies, etc.

Trousers = formal long pants; for weddings, etc.

I have never heard of slacks, but guessing they would be loose clothing.

Answer (score 2):

The real question that keeps popping up is the definition of "slacks".
It is a word that was used in the US clothing trade to describe what might be called "dress pants" in the US:  a type of garment that looks good with a blazer. This garment could be khakis, gabardine, some kind of cloth that holds a crease. "Dockers" would be an example of such a garment. I wouldn't imagine flannel trousers being called slacks, as they do not hold a crease. But that's just a personal impression.

Think of a man's suit, the type of cloth; now imagine just the trousers, and that there is no matching jacket: those would be slacks.

Delving further into the question of pants/slacks/trousers/jeans, all of these are pants of some kind, at least in US vernacular. Trousers is generally a term for pants that have a matching jacket, though the term "pants" is used as well. Slacks, as I said above, are "dressy" without being formal, and do not have a matching jacket. Jeans, on the other hand, are jeans. Denim riveted if truly authentic, exterior back pockets ... perhaps also with a small watch fob in the front right pocket; no crease down the front. Although garments can be cut like jeans, sewn like jeans and styled like jeans, if they are not made of cotton denim, they are not truly jeans.

One final note on "slacks" ... since there were many German Jewish immigrants in the garment trade a hundred years ago, I wonder whether the term does not come from Yiddish or German, just as "lox" (smoked salmon) comes from "Lachs" (German for salmon). That's one for a German linguist to pursue.

Answer (score 1):

The usage of the words "slacks" and "pants" to mean the same thing as the word trousers, seems to be from American English. I have heard these used by Americans. I have not heard those words used by British people. They normally use the word trousers and sometimes, some slang/informal words for them, like "strides".

This page lists the word "slacks" as another word for pants (in the trousers meaning): http://www.h2g2.com/approved_entry/A129647

Answer (score 1):

I am from the North West of England and I am very American on this subject, pants are not underware.  Trousers are smart and formal, you would not call the lower half of your addias track suit "jogging trousers"

If its raining I put on waterproof pants. (another word overpants)
If i am going out on a Friday night to a club i will ware trousers and a smart shirt.

I do not use the term slacks.

Comment: I now live in the South of England; it seems the southern English are pretty much on their own on this subject.  The rest of the world seems to say it in the American sense.  I think it maybe a historic class issue.  Northerner’s on the whole worked in industry and wore pants and underpants for work and trousers on a Sunday at church while Southeners wore suits in offices, with pants and trousers and the same on Sunday at church.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to depend on where you are from in the U.S., as well. In the Midwest, or at least the part where I am from, *slacks* refers to casual dress pants — what you'd wear to work, out for the night, to a dressy occasion where you don't want to look stiff, but do want to look good. *Blue jeans* don't fit this word. Jeans are jeans. *Pants* is a universal term. You subdivide, by using *slacks* etc., in order to define exactly what style you mean.

Answer (score 0):

In UK English, `Slacks` are `trousers` worn by women. This is by contrast with the other form of similar leg covering garment worn by women: `tights`. `Trousers` usually implies that the wearer is male.

In UK English, `pants` is a less formal word for `trousers`. It doesn't usually mean `underpants`, although if you `wet your pants`, I suppose this might mean `underpants`.

In recent years, `pants` has been used jocosely to mean useless/rotten/rubbish.

Comment: Just love down-voters who don't comment.

Comment: Sorry, I have downvoted because I think your answer is completely misleading. In the UK 'slacks is an old-fashioned word for trousers worn by both sexes (see @Kevdog answer). No modern woman would refer to her trousers as slacks. Likewise, you never hear 'pants' used for 'trousers' in the UK, except perhaps for American ideas such as 'jog pants'.

Comment: If a modern woman said Slacks, she would mean her trousers. Whether she /would/ say that is a different issue. While I have heard people refer to women's trousers as slacks (my mother used to, in the 1960's/1970's - I have never heard a Brit refer to mens trousers as slacks. Perhaps this is an American usage. Pants is used less for trousers since it acquired humourous connotations.

Answer (score 0):

Trou´sers
n. pl. 1. A garment worn by men and boys, extending from the waist to the knee or to the ankle, and covering each leg separately.

Trousers or "pants" can either be synonymous with pants or have a more formal connotation. Therefore, all trousers are pants, but not vice-versa: jeans are pants but not trousers, while slacks (formal pants) are both. This definition is consistent with other languages such as the Spanish pantalones, which is contrasted with pantalones cortos (shorts, or literally "short pants").

Comment: This definition seems to exist only in American English.

Comment: the UK definition of Trousers is: `An outer garment covering the body from the waist to the ankles, with a separate part for each leg.` So it's similar to the US definition.

Answer (score 0):

I have always thought of trousers as part of a suit or uniform.  Slacks look the same as suit trousers because they are made of more formal material, but are purchased separately.  They would be worn alone or with a sportcoat.  Pants are everything else, corderoys, chinos, jeans, and other less formal styles.